# jQuery - Displaying text when hidden changes when shown

Tags: jquery

I have a button that has text on it ... its formatted like so

```
<a href="" id="refl" class="button"><span>VIEW ALL CASES</span></a>
```

I have some jQuery at the moment that toggles a div when "refl" is clicked.

How would i change the text VIEW ALL CASES to say "VIEW ALL CASES" when the div is hidden, but display "CLOSE ALL CASES" when the div is showing?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  var span = $(this).find('span')
  span.html(span.html() == 'CLOSE ALL CASES' ? 'VIEW ALL CASES' : 'CLOSE ALL CASES');
});
```

I opt to use .html() instead of .text() because you can have other HTML markup inside your span.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#ref1").click(function(){
    var div = $("#theDivToToggle");
    div.toggle();
    $(this).find("span").text(div.is(":visible") ? "CLOSE ALL CASES" : "SHOW ALL CASES");
});
```

Comment: The particular advantage of this approach over some of the others posted is that it uses the actual visibility of `#theDivToToggle` to determine what text should be showing. You could look at the current text (e.g., if it says "CLOSE ALL CASES" then change it to say "VIEW ALL CASES") but that can get you out-of-sync with the actual contents if ever you show/hide them in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#refl').click(function() {
   //select elements
   var $span = $('span', this);
   var $div = $('div#theOneYouAreHidding'); //this is div you hide/show

   //check text to see if we need to hide or show
   if($span.text() == 'VIEW ALL CASES')
   {
      $div.show();
      $span.text('CLOSE ALL CASES');
   }
   else
   {
      $div.hide();
      $span.text('VIEW ALL CASES');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#refl').click(function() {

   $(this).text(function() {
       return $('#your-element:visible').length ? 'CLOSE ALL CASES' : 'SHOW ALL CASES';
   });

   // hide code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#ref1').toggle(
  function () {
    $('div').show(); // div selector here
    $(this).find('span').html('CLOSE ALL CASES');
  },
  function () {
    $('div').hide(); // div selector here
    $(this).find('span').html('VIEW ALL CASES');
  },
);
```